# How to create a VM Image from an already uploaded VHD in Azure using API

Tags: ruby, api, powershell, azure, virtual-machine

I've created a VHD in Azure using packer and uploaded it to Azure. So it is now available in a storage account. Now, I want to create a VM Image out of it which I can publish in marketplace, using API. I have searched the docs and seen powershell's [Add-​Azure​VM​Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/add-azurevmimage?view=azuresmps-3.7.0), but I need the same using API (Well, a Ruby library would be perfect).

1. I've created a VHD using packer and it is available in a storage account
2. I need to create an image from that VHD. The blog post titled "VM Image" speaks about running a VM and taking a snapshot of that VM as an image, while I don't want that VM creation process.

To be more clear, I need something similar to step 3 in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/classic/create-upload-vhd … which doesn't require a local vhd file

Comment: Which blob post titled "VM Image"? Is it this one https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/vm-image-blog-post/?

Comment: Yes. I couldn't add more than two links as I didn't have >10 reputation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you already uploaded .vhd file into your Storage account then you should run this PowerShell to create image out of this .vhd file.

Add-AzureVmImage -ImageName 'xyz' -Label 'xyz' -MediaLocation 'location of the VHD' -OS Windows

Comment: Hey Abhishek,

I explicitly need to use API (or better - Ruby wrapper) for this. Not PowerShell. But, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the REST API [`Create a virtual machine image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/manageddisks/images/images-create) with the json request body `Create a virtual machine image from a blob` like below is you want.

```
{
  "location": "West US",
  "properties": {
    "storageProfile": {
      "osDisk": {
        "osType": "Windows",
        "blobUri": "https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/osimages/osimage.vhd",
        "osState": "generalized"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And for using Azure Ruby SDK, I found the method [`create_or_update`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/blob/master/management/azure_mgmt_compute/lib/generated/azure_mgmt_compute/images.rb#L25) of the model `Azure::ARM::Compute`, but there is not any sample code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Peter,

I was able to use create_or_update to create an ImageOSDisk from VHD and hence an image. But, apparently, to deploy a VM from it, the option "type: fromImage" needs to be specified while creating the image. But ImageOSDisk doesn't have that option, only OSDisk does. I can't use OSDisk because it doesn't have the "os_state" property. 

Do you know any solution out of this?

Comment: I've added the code I use here - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/issues/754